# How to determine the ON UPDATE/DELETE actions for an existing Access relationship?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I get the ON UPDATE action and ON DELETE action for MS Access for a foreign key relationship constraint in MS Access?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT szRelationship as ConstraintName,
szObject as TableName,
szColumn as ColumnName,
szReferencedObject as ParentTableName,
szReferencedColumn as ParentColumnName
FROM MSysRelationships
where szObject not like 'MSys%'
```

Comment: For MS Access 2010+, look into [data macros](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200).

Comment: I am looking to get the current actions, not create new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Referential Integrity details appear to be exposed in the [grbit] column of the [MSysRelationships] table:

```
MSysRelationships.grbit

bit  value  meaning
---  -----  -----------------------------------------------
  0      1  1 = one-to-one relationship (0 = one-to-many)
  1      2  don't enforce Referential Integrity
  8    256  ON UPDATE CASCADE
 12   4096  ON DELETE CASCADE
```

So, for example,

- a one-to-many relationship with both ON UPDATE CASCADE and ON DELETE CASCADE would have a value of 1000100000000 = 4352
- a one-to-one relationship with both ON UPDATE CASCADE and ON DELETE CASCADE would have a value of 1000100000001 = 4353.

Comment: An excellent answer. You can use the bitwise [`And` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators) to test for the bit flags, e.g. `grbit And 256 = 256` to test the  On Update Cascade, these are valid in Access SQL.